# Resourse.designer.cs can't rebuild android Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Today I am trying to make a start in programming for Android in C# using Xamarin. However, when I go to their docs and follow an example to play audio ([Here is the link to the audio docs)](http://docs.xamarin.com/recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio). When I add this line of code:

```
    _player = MediaPlayer.Create(this, Resource.Raw.test);
```

I get this error:

```
    E:\Android Apps\Hardcore_Gabber_App\HardcoreGabberApp\MainActivity.cs(48,48): Error CS0117: 'HardcoreGabberApp.Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Raw' (CS0117) (HardcoreGabberApp)
```

And this is how I have my folders:

[image: Folder]

And still it cant find "Raw". Deleting the Recourse.designer.cs and then rebuild is not working. Then I am getting even more errors and the Recourse.designer.cs is not rebuilding. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seemed that I had to add the files manually by adding right clicking on a folder and press add files instead of drag and drop to fix the issue: [image: this]