# Xamarin.Forms PCL SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database and 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Raw'

Tags: c#, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

Today I am facing with this issue: I got such a exception :

> SQLite.SQLiteException: file is encrypted or is not a database

I am doing project regarding this guide: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/databases/ . 
This is my Database class where I am initialize Connection and Table creation:

```
public class ThingDatabase
{
    SQLiteConnection database;

    public ThingDatabase()
    {
        database = DependencyService.Get<ISQLite>().GetConnection();
        database.CreateTable<ThingObj>();
    }
}
```

Here is my object class:

```
public class ThingObj
{
    public ThingObj()
    {
    }
    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ThingNumber { get; set; }
    public bool IsStarted { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my created `SQLite_Android` class regarding example:

```
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(SQLite_Android))]
...
{
    public class SQLite_Android : ISQLite
    {
        public SQLite_Android() { }
        public SQLite.SQLiteConnection GetConnection() {
            var sqliteFilename = "ThingSQLite.db3";
            string documentsPath = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
            var path = Path.Combine(documentsPath, sqliteFilename);
            Console.WriteLine(path);
            if (!File.Exists(path))
            {
               var s = Forms.Context.Resources.OpenRawResource(Resource.Raw.Database);
               FileStream writeStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write);
               ReadWriteStream(s, writeStream);
            }
            var conn = new SQLite.SQLiteConnection(path);
            return conn;
        }
        void ReadWriteStream(Stream readStream, Stream writeStream)
        {
           int Length = 256;
           Byte[] buffer = new Byte[Length];
           int bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
           while (bytesRead > 0)
           {
               writeStream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
               bytesRead = readStream.Read(buffer, 0, Length);
           }
           readStream.Close();
           writeStream.Close();
        }
}
```

When I am debugging, after `database.CreateTable<ThingObj>();` breakpoint, I am getting that exception and redirected to `SQLite.cs` class last line.
**EDIT :** Regarding AkashAmin suggestion I changed sqliteFilename to another string name and solved previous issue. Now I want to create database file in path, but unfortunately `Resource.Designer.cs` file do not auto generate Raw partial class in `Resource.designer.cs` . I am getting this error:

> 'Resource' does not contain a definition for 'Raw'

Comment: Your database might be corrupted. Try again after changing the SqliteFilename

Comment: @AkashAmin lol it worked, but now I got another error, just a second, I will eddit my question.

Comment: Do have any RAW folders?

Comment: @AkashAmin Yes I created raw folder manually

Comment: Try adding the files in it manually. There was this problem http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18988408/resourse-designer-cs-cant-rebuild-android-xamarin